# Menu bar 100% width

Tags: html, css

I've got a menu bar here: ---
Now when you resize the window (so there appears a horizontal scrollbar) and you scroll to the right, the background is vanished! How can I solve this problem?

Comment: white-space:nowrap; is preventing the background from being displayed properly when resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kevin;  may be you have to define `min-width` for your menu bar.

**for example**

```
.menu{
min-width:1200px;
width:1300px;
}
```

for more :
[Min width in window resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802455/min-width-in-window-resizing)

http://friendlybit.com/css/min-width-and-max-width-template/

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap everything in a new `div`, and apply `min-width: 960px` to that.

```
<div id="container" style="min-width:960px">
    <div id="ovoMenu"> 
        ..
    </div> 
    <div id="ovoSubmenu"> 
        ..
    </div>
</div>
```

You could just set the `min-width` on `body`, but I'm not sure what else will be going on that page.