# Set minimum width for Twitter Bootstrap page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width

I have searched a lot (here and on the net) about setting the minimum display width for a Twitter Bootstrap page. I want to set the minimum display to 360px so the layout wouldn't change. I tried setting the min-width in the CSS code:

```
html, body {
  min-width: 360px;
}
```

But no luck.

Please advise.

Comment: I want to limit the browser width so user can't change it to lower than 360px......

Comment: What about setting min-height as well?

Comment: I don't need to limit the height of the page, I just want to prevent users from changing the width of the browser to lower than 360px so the layout will not be changed, my bootstrap page was limit the minimum width of the browser to 360px but I don't know what I have changed in the CSS custom code and now I can change the width to lower than that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page seems to answer your question:
[Min width in window resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802455/min-width-in-window-resizing)

As far as I can tell, the thing you were missing was setting the width to auto.