# min-width of browser window

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a min-width to my page so that when I resize the browser window it should stop at the min-width value. But I can't get to work it.

I tried the following but I still can make it smaller beyond that point. Anyone has a solution?

```
body { min-width: 290px; }
```

**UPDATE:**
So I think with what I wanted I would need to use some javascript. The CSS would only apply the elements but not the window. I got that. Also what I experienced and confused me was, while resizing the window (make it smaller in my example), the actual window width was determined by the currently open tabs. The window would only shrink so little, that every tab is still clickable. (If you have a lot of tabs open. Like >10 or so).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Min width in window resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802455/min-width-in-window-resizing)

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Look in code below: 
To see the block I added height 200px

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <body>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  background-color: white;
}
body {
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 290px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Try it interactively:
https://codepen.io/artysimple/pen/mBxeNK?editors=1100

I you want to center main content on your web site I advice you to use a **global class container** for this.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot stop window to resize by applying min-width to body or any other html element
You can only do that using JavaScript